# How to prove existence of a solution of this determinant equation?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, determinant

Let $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a real diagonal matrix where $\sum_i D_{ii}<0$. Let also $R\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be real (possibly) non-symmetric (irreducible) matrices with right and left eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ (associated with eigenvalue 1); i.e.  $R\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{1}^T L=\mathbf{1}^T$. How to prove that below equation has a solution $x$ where $|x|>1$?
$$
\det\bigg(\underbrace{(L-xI)(R-xI)+(x-1)D}_{\triangleq Q}\bigg)=0.
$$

Any hint/help is really appreciated.

**Note:** In the special scenario when $L=R^T$, one can see that $Q$ is symmetric, and it is not hard to show that $\mathbf{1}^TQ\mathbf{1}<0$ for some $\lambda=1+\epsilon$ with sufficiently small $\epsilon$, therefore $Q$ has at least one negative eigenvalue (eigenvalues are real by symmetricity). Since for $x>>1$ the determinant function $\det(Q)>>0$ (and continuity of eigenvalues), thus there must exists $\lambda^\star>1$ such that the equation holds. One cannot use this approach in the general case, since $Q$ is generally non-symmetric and the numerical range does not coincide with convex hull of the eigenvalues and eigenvalues can be complex (i.e. a negative Reighley quotient doesn't imply existence of a negative eigenvalue).

Comment: It might help to  know exactly what happens in case $n=2$. I want to change the variable to $\xi=x-1$ and replace $L,R$ by $L-I, R-I$ so that the row/column sums are $0$. With generic $L-I=[a -a//b -b]$ and generic $R-I$ and generic $D$ a CAS must crunch out the roots (one is surely 0?) I'd do by hand but ..

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, let me see if I can get anything :)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Even in case of 2-by-2 matrices the root is messy, but setting some numerical values, I can see that there exists a real value solution bigger than one (besides the trivial solution 1). I was thinking if one can use implicit function theorem or some other tricks to show existence?

Comment: @ancientmathematician If $L$ and $R$ were symmetric (with eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ and eigenvalue 1), it would be easy since one could compute $x^TQx$ ($Q$ being the matrix in the determinant function) with $x=\mathbf{1}$ and sow that there exists a real $\lambda$ sufficiently close (above) to one such that $x^TQx<0$ and since for large $x$ the det(.) function must be positive, thus there exists a $\lambda^\star>1$ such that the equation holds.

Comment: Yes, I'd computed $1^T Q 1= -(x-1)(x-(1-\frac{1}{n}\text{tr}(D)))$ but could not use it.

Comment: I solved this problem and will post the solution in a while. I hope I will get my reputation points back!

Comment: @vulture Unfortunately, you will [never](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) get your bounty reputation back, I'm sorry. However, the only way you could get your lost reputation is to receive upvotes for the answer.